# Can I do this with Windows Installer (vs.net 2010)?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I need to do the following tasks for creating an installer and I need to figure out the best approach to take.  I'm currently thinking of using windows installer, which comes with vs.net 2010, but I'm not sure it can achieve the following:
1) When the user first installs, check that .NET framework 4.0 is installed on their computer.  If not, install it.
2) Create a few directory folders
3) Place a shortcut on the user's desktop
4) Place the software into the user's Start Menu.
5) Install the software into the newly created directory

What's the best approach to handle this?  Can Windows Installer (vs.net 2010) accomplish this?  
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can do all of what you are asking, it also is being replaced by InstallShield 2010 Limited Edition. This [article gives your options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721500.aspx).

1. Checking for .Net 4.0 is done by going to the **Setup Project Properties --> Prerequisites** then select the .Net 4.0 Framework that you want(Client or Full) and select *Download prerequisites from the same location as my application*
2. You create folders by using the `File System Editor` adding the new folder to the folder that you want.
3. You use the same 'File System Editor' to do what your question's 3,4 & 5 are asking.

Take a look at these articles:

1. [Visual Studio Installer Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx)
2. [File Installation Management in Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ddxk2ye.aspx)

Comment: @user1070194 You should mark one of these answers as the answer if it answered your question. It will add closure to your question and help future users.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to build MSI installer in Visual Studio 2010 is to use **[Votive](http://wix.sourceforge.net/votive.html)** - it is the Visual Studio package for WiX (Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset).